# declaring a variable without assigning a value in the constructor when creating an instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I want to create a Node REST API with Typescript and created a basic class managing the Express application

```
import express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'http';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';

import { IWebServer } from './IWebServer';
import { RoutesLoader } from './routes/RoutesLoader';
import * as webServerConfig from '../../config/webServerConfig';
import { IPlugin } from './plugins/IPlugin';
import { LoggerPlugin } from './plugins/LoggerPlugin';
import { CorsPlugin } from './plugins/CorsPlugin';
import { BodyParserPlugin } from './plugins/BodyParserPlugin';

@injectable()
export class WebServer implements IWebServer {
    public app: express.Application;
    public httpServer: Server;
    private port: any;

    constructor () {
        this.app = express();
        this.httpServer = null;
        this.port = webServerConfig.port;
    }

    public startListening(): void 
    {
        const plugins: IPlugin[] = [
            new LoggerPlugin(),
            new CorsPlugin(),
            new BodyParserPlugin()
        ];

        for (const plugin of plugins) { // load all the middleware plugins
            plugin.register();
        }

        new RoutesLoader(); // load all the routes

        try {
            this.httpServer = this.app.listen(this.port);
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }

    public stopListening(): void 
    {
        this.httpServer.close();
    }
}
```

This code looks fine to me but the problem is that I have to assign a value to `httpServer` in the class constructor. As you can see I assign a value to it later in `startListening`. But I can't assign `null` to it in the constructor. `undefined` neither. This type is not nullable. How can I declare this variable without assigning a value to it when creating an instance of this class?

Comment: If you only assign a value sometime later, then it's possible to be in a state where the value *is* `null`/does not exist, so you *must* declare the type as nullable/optional.

Comment: hm the problem is that the type `Server` comes from Nodes `http` module so I didn't create this variable type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your `httpServer` field can be `null` and also *is* `null` before a call to `startListening`.

Therefor you have to specify that in the type declaration like this:

```
public httpServer: Server | null;
```

and then handle the `null` cases in further methods:

```
public stopListening(): void 
{
  if (this.httpServer === null) {
    throw "Not listening, call "startListening()" first";
  }
  this.httpServer.close();
}
```